# ASP.NET MVC ajax custom filter and paging

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I try to use Datatable in mvc application. I have a custom form to filter values, and load data into table by ajax.

```
$('#tblProducts').DataTable({
serverSide: true,

bFilter: false,
"oLanguage": {
    "sUrl": "/Content/DataTables/languages/Russian.json"
},
"ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/Product/Products",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#searchForm").serializeObject() + "&draw=" + data.draw + "&start=" + data.start + "&length=" + data.length
    });
}
});
```

In controller i pass my viewmodel to filter values and paging info.
But  my table didn't show any content.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Products(ProductSearchViewModel model, int draw, int start, int length){//filtering data...}
```

json

```
${"draw":1,"iTotalRecords":1048,"iTotalDisplayRecords":10,"aaData":[["1","1001F","GoodWill","Воздушные","16","0,0008","0,87","False"],["2","1002F","GoodWill","Тормозные колодки","16","0,000928","1,505","False"],["3","1003F","GoodWill","Тормозные колодки","10","0,001716","1,595","True"],["4","1004F","GoodWill","Тормозные колодки","16","0,0008","1,88","True"],["5","1007F","GoodWill","Тормозные колодки","13","0,001804","2,46","True"],["6","1008F","GoodWill","Тормозные колодки","10","0,001716","1,6","True"],["7","1010F","GoodWill","Тормозные колодки","16","0,00096","1,63","True"],["8","1012F","GoodWill","Тормозные колодки","16","0,001494","0,023902","True"],["9","1013F","GoodWill","Тормозные колодки","16","0,0008","0,92","True"],["10","1013FX","GoodWill","Тормозные колодки","16","0,0008","0,93","True"]]}
```

This json come to client, I can see it in fiddler, but table does not show anything.
And there is no javascript errors in Chrome console.
What shall I do to display data in table?